# How can I create a charge without generating an invoice for it in Recurly?

Tags: node.js, recurly

Using `node-recurly`. The idea is to create a charge without generating an invoice, then create a subscription and have recurly attach the charge to the subscription invoice. However, when I create a charge, the invoice gets generated automatically for it, so the user gets two separate invoices in the email: one for the charge, and one for the subscription.
This is the charge object that I use:

```
const shippingCharge = {
      amount_in_cents: parseFloat(shippingMethod.amount) * 100,
      currency: 'USD',
      description: `${shippingMethod.provider} ${shippingMethod.servicelevel_name} shipping`,
      account: {
        account_code: activationCode,
      },
    };
```

I pass it to this function that creates a charge:

```
recurly.transactions.create(chargeObject, (response) => {
    ... blah blah blah
  });
```

`recurly.subscriptions.create` is being called next (calls are being made *sequentially* using promises). The end result is two invoices instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Recurly's documentation is confusing. When I was trying to create a charge, I made an assumption that I have to create a transaction. After contacting support, I was provided with the link to [create a charge](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-a-charge). If you look at the code examples on the right, they reference *Recurly_Adjustment*, not transaction object. So **to create a charge I have to create an adjustment**, not a transaction. Switching to proper API call fixed the issue and I received a single invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is correct. You will also need to use `revenue_schedule_type: at_invoice` if you want the charges together. The Recurly API docs do not include NodeJS examples. Here you go:

```
return recurly.adjustments.create(accountId, {
  unit_amount_in_cents: parseFloat(shippingMethod.amount) * 100,
  currency: 'USD',
  description: `${shippingMethod.provider} ${shippingMethod.servicelevel_name} shipping`,
  revenue_schedule_type: 'at_invoice',
  accounting_code: accountingCode,
}).then(() => {
  // ...create an invoice, subscription, or whatever
});
```